# Are ia64 processors ever used for Windows PCs? If so, how many people are using them?

Tags: windows, cpu, desktop-computer, intel-itanium

How many people on average are using ia64 powered Windows desktop PCs? I know this really can't be accurate, but just on average, like 1? 10? 10000?

Thanks

-edit: wasn't thinking correctly: I didn't mean just desktop pcs, what i meant was computer use in general, other than servers.

Comment: Edited the title, because Itanium has an existence beyond Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more likely 0, Itanium is designed for high end servers.
There is few probability that someone use it as desktop PC, may be as a workstation for specific jobs (3D Rendering, etc.) but not for daily task.
And recently microsoft has announced the end of support for Itanium processor.

Comment: That what I expected to hear, seeing that they are marketed as processors for high end servers. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: I would agree - not many are sold in a year... I think the number is the low 1000's. I would expect the number of people using them as workstations on ANY OS would be less than 1000.  I wouldn't say zero since people like me might do it...if I had one I didn't want to use as a server... but even then, it wouldn't be my only workstation.